# Laravel - php eval with blade compileString

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eval, laravel-blade

I'm trying to parse a blade template string into php format and use **eval()** to evaluate string as php code

```
 $array = [
     'foo' => 'bar',
     'bar' => 'foo'
 ];
 $content = '@foreach($array as $value){{$value}}@endforeach';
 $blade = Blade::compileString($content);
 $php = eval($blade);
```

This is my code for testing so far and it throws exception

> ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '<',
>   expecting end of file

value of **$blade** after **compileString()**

```
<?php $__currentLoopData = $array; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $value): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?><?php echo e($value); ?><?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
```

What causes this error? Is eval() not compatible with the way compileString() is parsing blade into php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

> The code must not be wrapped in opening and closing PHP tags, i.e. `'echo "Hi!";'` must be passed instead of `'<?php echo "Hi!"; ?>'`. It is still possible to leave and re-enter PHP mode though using the appropriate PHP tags, e.g. `'echo "In PHP mode!"; ?>In HTML mode!<?php echo "Back in PHP mode!";'`.

Your blade is wrapped in `<?php` tags, and the compilation fails. Remove the enclosing PHP tags, but leave the interstitial tags.